How to Parallelize Puppeteer Tasks Using Worker Threads in Node.js?
I'm working on a Node.js project where I need to run multiple Puppeteer instances in parallel to scrape data from a website. I've read that using worker_threads can help achieve this by running tasks concurrently, but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly.
Here's what I've done so far:

Launched a Puppeteer browser instance.
Created multiple worker threads and passed the Puppeteer browser's
WebSocket endpoint to each worker.
Each worker connects to the Puppeteer browser and performs its task.

However, only one worker seems to execute correctly, and the others only start if I manually interact with them. Additionally, I encounter timeout errors, which suggests that the workers are not being managed properly.
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  devtools: false,
  channel: 'chrome',
});
const wsEndpoint = browser.wsEndpoint();
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  new Worker(WORKER_PATH, {
        workerData: {
          wsEndpoint,
          url: '<some url>',
        },
     );
}

worker.js
    import { connect } from 'puppeteer-core';

   (async () => {
  try {
    const { wsEndpoint, url } = workerData as {
      wsEndpoint: string;
      url: string;
    };
    const browser = await connect({
      browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
      defaultViewport: null,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 1024 });
    // some code`


Puppeteer runs the browser as a subprocess, so I highly doubt parallelization will help much. The Node single thread doesn't have to do much work, just issue CDP calls to the browser and do a lot of waiting for things to happen. That's why the API is almost entirely async. While it's waiting for one browser to act (which is most of the time), it can issue commands to other browsers. You might want to step back and describe your actual use case, maybe show a minimal script that fails to perform as you expect. There may be easy, obvious optimizations you're overlooking.
